# HTML de shortcode no se muestra correctamente

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Estoy intentando crear un formulario dentro de un `shortcode`, pero al imprimir el `shortcode` este se sale del sitio donde lo coloco dentro de div:

```
// Shortcode para formulario
function formulario_menu() {
?>

<form id="register_form" action="/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=envio_menu" method="POST">
  <?php wp_nonce_field(basename(__FILE__), 'menu_nonce'); ?>
</form>

<?php
}

add_shortcode('form_menu', 'formulario_menu');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto pasa porque internamente el contenido se guarda en una variable y se concatena, en tu caso no concatenas, sino que directamente haces un echo del contenido haciendo que no tenga espacio y se imprima en otro lado.

Lo recomendable es que concatenes el contenido en una variable y hacer un return de ese contenido, puedes guardar el almacenamiento en buffer en una variable y retornarlo para eso, por ejemplo.

```
function formulario_menu(){ 
    ob_start(); ?>

    <form id="register_form" action="/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=envio_menu" method="POST">

        <?php wp_nonce_field(basename(__FILE__), 'menu_nonce'); ?>
    </form>

<?php 
    
    $output = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $output;

}
add_shortcode( 'form_menu', 'formulario_menu' );
```

Comment: Gracias funciono